# How to transparent status bar without change NaviBar android

Tags: android, dictionary, statusbar, transparent

My trouble is I could not make a transparent status bar only like uber map.
Here is uber made : [image]

I tried using

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

But it makes transparent all status and navibar. I don't want to this. Just only status bar. Could you help me, guy? Just hit the comment any thing to suggest me

My code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    style="@style/AppThemeMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_maps"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_maps_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <goixeom.com.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/term"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_margin_nav"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:text="Quyền riêng tư"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <goixeom.com.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/dang_xuat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_margin_nav"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:text="Điều khoản"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My app screenshot : 
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: do you want all status bar to be transparent in your app ?

Comment: yes. All status bar but not affect to Navibar.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

just add this line to your **base application theme**

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

or programatically

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these line in activity

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

Comment: well, It only makes status bar color gray. My map not fit to statusbar and color status's not transparent.

I have added source code in my question.

Comment: Have you removed the <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> from the style